# Валидация только одной формы

Tags: activerecord, yii2, валидация

Всем здравствуйте. Есть виджет

```
namespace app\components;

use app\models\Reports;
use app\models\ReportsData;
use app\models\ReportsUser;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Widget;

class VoteWidget extends Widget {

    public $id_reports;
    public $data;

    public function getModelData($id){
        $model = Reports::find()->where(['tb_reports.id'=>$id])->joinWith('reportData')->one();

        if($model !== null)
            return $model;
    }

    public function run() {
        $model = $this->getModelData($this->id_reports);

        $model_form = new ReportsData;

        if ($model_form->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model_form->validate()) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO tb_reports_user(data_id, user_id, report_id)VALUES(:data_id, :user_id, :report_id)', ['data_id' => $model_form->report_data, 'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id, ':report_id' => $model->report_id])->execute();
            ReportsData::updateAll(['can_take' => 0], 'id=:id', [':id' => $this->id_reports]);
        }

        return $this->render('list_vote', ['model' => $model, 'model_form'=>$model_form]);
    }

}
```

list_vote.php

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
    echo $form->field($model_form, 'report_data', ['enableLabel' => false])->radioList($items, ['separator' => '<br />']);

    echo Html::submitButton('Моя тема!', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']);

    ActiveForm::end();
```

Так вот вся проблема, что этот виджет вызывается в другому виджете ListView, т.е. этих форм может быть 1, 2, 5, 10 сколько угодно, но беда в том, что когда я нажимаю кнопку на одной какой-то, это применяется сразу для всех форм. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Как это исправить? :(

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно написано. Вы имеете ввиду, что виджет имеет свою форму, которая может находиться внутри другой формы, которых может быть 1,2,5,10? Тогда естественно у вас ошибка в этом.

Если я ошибаюсь, попробуйте поиграть с параметром `id` формы каждого виджета, он должен быть уникальным.